# Math - Relation of 2 algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, math, relation, asymptotic-complexity

Two expression with A and B:

[image: img]

```
A = 2^(3(log_3 n))
B = 6(n^2)
```

As i need to indicate whether A is big-Oh, big-Omega, or big-theta of B,
is that `A=O(B)`?

how to solve this?

Comment: your question make no sense  what has to do this with algorithm (I assume `A,B` are complexities of some algorithms) but that is irrelevant for comparison. What do you mean by `A=O(B)?` how to solve what? Do you want to find threshold `n` value so `A(n) == B(n)` instead ? If `A,B` are indeed complexities then you should measure the threshold  as estimated value will be way off on modern architectures

Comment: sorry for the misleading

Comment: so you need to prove that `lim(n -> +inf) A(n) >= lim(n -> +inf) B(n)` that is not programming task but pure math ... (however you can solve it numerically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do a *simple math* (`log(x, b)` stands for a logarithm on `b` base; `log(x) = log(x, 2)` is a binary logarithm):

```
A = 2 ** (3 * log(n, 3)) = 
    2 ** (log(n ** 3, 3)) = 
    2 ** (log(n ** 3) / log(3)) = 
    n ** (3 / log(3)) =
    n ** (log(2 ** 3, 3)) =
    n ** (log(8, 3)) ~
    n ** 1.8928...
```

When

```
B = 6 * n**2
```

Finally, algorithm `A` has a better complexity than `B` (`1.8928… < 2`):

```
A = O(n**(log(8, 3)) ~ O(n**1.8928)
B = O(6 * n**2) = O(n**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to amplify the already given answers:
We can rewrite the function `A(n)=2^(3(log_3 n))`:

```cpp
A(n) = 2^(3*(log_3 n))
     = exp( ln(2^(3*(log_3 n))) )
     = exp( 3*(log_3 n)*ln(2) )
     = exp( 3*ln(n)/ln(3)*ln(2) )
     = exp( 3*ln(2)/ln(3)*ln(n) )
     = n^(3*ln(2)/ln(3))
```

where `ln` is the natural logarithm. So we get
`A(n)/B(n) = 1/6 * n^(3*ln(2)/ln(3)-2)` with `3*ln(2)/ln(3)-2<0`
and therefore

```cpp
lim_{n to inf} abs(A(n)/B(n)) = 0 < inf
```

i.e. `A=O(B)`

Since `A` converges, the limt, the limit inferior and limit superior are equal:

```cpp
liminf_{n to inf} abs(A(n)/B(n)) = 0 (!>0)
```

i.e. `A!=Omega(B)` and thereby also `A!=Theta(B)`

For the definitions just see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation